# What is the average sensitivity of a quantum circuit with depth $d$ and size $s$?

Tags: quantum-computing, circuit-complexity, quantum-information, probabilistic-circuits

We have some quantum circuit $C$ with $k$ ancillae and $n$ input bits of depth $d$ and size $s$, and we can define a function $f$ which, for any $x \in \{0, 1\}^n$, is the random variable which is the first bit of output from $C|x, 0^k\rangle$, i.e. $Pr(f(x) = 1) = |(C|x, 0^k\rangle)_0|^2$. We define the sensitivity of this function at $x$ as $s(f, x) = \sum_{y : ham(x, y) = 1} |Pr(f(x) = 1) - Pr(f(y) = 1)|$ and the average sensitivity $S(f) = \mathbb{E_x[s(f, x)]}$. We know by an extension of Boppana's 97 paper on the average sensitivity of circuits to probabilistic classical circuits (those which we can compare these to), that these have average sensitivity $O(log(s))^{d-1}$. I think exploring the average sensitivity of these quantum circuits would be a nice way to resolve some of the open problems stated [here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/856756/).

My intuition is that the average sensitivity will be higher than in the classical case, but still lower than the maximal average sensitivity which one gets for parity, showing that $QAC_{wf}^k \neq QAC^k$.

I'd be quite satisfied with approaches to use or just interesting discussions of this as answers, as I don't expect for someone to actually resolve this here.